# Polaroid + with I-type film

Tags: polaroid

I recently bought a Polaroid plus and I-type film but am very disappointed with the color quality.  I have color polaroid prints from 25 years ago that still have more vibrant color than these new photos.  Would i be better off getting a 600 camera and using the 600 film?  I'm excited to have a Polaroid camera again but very disappointed with the prints.

Comment: I'm surprised you're let down by the colour saturation, as PO's latest gen 3.0 colour film has drastically increased contrast adding the substantial saturation. In some cases it's even so severe PO wants to decrease it slightly. Are you sure your exposures aren't off? It helps to slightly underexpose your shots for increased contrast. For reference maybe check my Polaroid shots' colours at @timvrhn on instagram

Comment: For a more reliable answer, you may wish to include specific details on which film [year] you are using and the results you are getting - The "New" Polaroid being produced today is an entirely new product, while "new old stock" of original Polaroid will be of questionable reliability by this point.

Answer (score 1):

Polaroid went out of business long ago. The Polaroid Originals Project is a company that wound up with some OG Polaroid manufacture machines but had to recreate the emulsions.

As far as I know, the only difference between I type and 600 is the inclusion of a battery to operate the camera. The emulsions are the same. So, you will see no real difference in going from I type to 600 or even to Spectra, save the size difference. SX70, however, is a slower ISO emulsion and will have different character than I type/600...so if you want to try something new, go with SX70.